# Automatically stack every nth column of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, stack, subset

I have a date frame called DF with, say, three variables that repeat each other cyclically:

```
      A      B      C      A      B      C 
1    a1     b1     c1     a5     b5     c5
2    a2     b2     c2     a6     b6     c6
3    a3     b3     c3     a7     b7     c7
4    a4     b4     c4     a8     b8     c8
```

I want to stack the first A column on the second A column (and on the third, and fourth and so on, if they exist), and do the same with the other variables, and then save the result as new objects (as vectors, for example).
So what I want to obtain is

```
V_A <- c(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8)
V_B <- c(b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8)
V_C <- c(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8)
```

While it's very easy to do it manually, like this

```
V_A <- DF[,seq(1, ncol(DF), 3]
V_A <- stack(DF)
V_B <- DF[,seq(2, ncol(DF), 3]
V_B <- stack(DF)
V_C <- DF[,seq(3, ncol(DF), 3]
V_C <- stack(DF)
```

what I'm looking for is a code that does this automatically, so that it will work for data frames with every number of variables without having to write ad-hoc codes every time.
To sum up, the code should:
1) select every nth column in the data frame
2) stack this columns
3) save the result in new objects automatically created

I feel there must be a way to do this but I haven't succeeded so far. Thanks very much in advance.

EDIT
Let's say I am in a slightly different situation, in which the columns repeat but not with exactly the same name, and I still want to do the same thing. So I have:

```
     A1      B1      C1      A2      B2      C2 
1    a11     b11     c11     a25     b25     c25
2    a12     b12     c12     a26     b26     c26
3    a13     b13     c13     a27     b27     c27
4    a14     b14     c14     a28     b28     c28
```

and I want:

```
V_A <- c(a11,a12,a13,a14,a25,a26,a27,a28)
V_B <- c(b11,b12,b13,b14,b25,b26,b27,b28)
V_C <- c(c11,c12,c13,c14,c25,c26,c27,c28)
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some alternatives. No packages are used.

**1) aperm** Create a 3d array `a`, permute the dimensions and reshape into a matrix `m` and then convert that to a data frame.  This one only works if all values are of the same type.  (2) and (3) do not have this limitation.

```
k <- 3
nr <- nrow(DF)
nc <- ncol(DF)
unames <- unique(names(DF))

a <- array(as.matrix(DF), c(nr, k, nc/k))
m <- matrix(aperm(a, c(1, 3, 2)),, k, dimnames = list(NULL, unames))
as.data.frame(m, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

giving:

```
   A  B  C
1 a1 b1 c1
2 a2 b2 c2
3 a3 b3 c3
4 a4 b4 c4
5 a5 b5 c5
6 a6 b6 c6
7 a7 b7 c7
8 a8 b8 c8
```

If we are in the situation given in the question's EDIT then replace `unames` with the following where DF2 is DF with the revised names as per Note at end:

```
unames <- unique(sub("\\d*$", "", names(DF2)))
```

**2) lapply**  This generalizes the code in the question. `unames` is defined above:

```
L <- lapply(split(as.list(DF), names(DF)), unlist)
as.data.frame(L, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

giving:

```
   A  B  C
1 a1 b1 c1
2 a2 b2 c2
3 a3 b3 c3
4 a4 b4 c4
5 a5 b5 c5
6 a6 b6 c6
7 a7 b7 c7
8 a8 b8 c8
```

With the input shown in the question's EDIT it could be done like this where `DF2` is given reproducibly in the Note at the end.

```
names0 <- sub("\\d*$", "", names(DF2))   # names without the trailing digits
L <- lapply(split(as.list(DF2), names0), unlist)
as.data.frame(L, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**3) reshape**  `nc` and `unames` are from above. `varying` is a list with `k` components such as that the ith component contains the index vector `c(i, i+k, ...)`. It seems that `reshape` does not like duplicated names so we have given it `setNames(DF, 1:nc)` as the input. This solution does have the advantage of also generating the index vectors `time` and `id` which relate the output to the input data.

```
varying <- split(1:nc, names(DF))
reshape(setNames(DF, 1:nc), dir = "long", varying = varying, v.names = unames)
```

giving:

```
    time  A  B  C id
1.1    1 a1 b1 c1  1
2.1    1 a2 b2 c2  2
3.1    1 a3 b3 c3  3
4.1    1 a4 b4 c4  4
1.2    2 a5 b5 c5  1
2.2    2 a6 b6 c6  2
3.2    2 a7 b7 c7  3
4.2    2 a8 b8 c8  4
```

With the input shown in the question's EDIT it actually simplifies.  We no longer need to use `setNames(DF, 1:nc)` but can just use the data frame as is as input. Also, we can use `varying=TRUE` (also see @thelatemail's comment) instead of calculating a complex argument for `varying`.  The input `DF2` is as shown in the Note at the end and `names0` is as in (2) above.

```
reshape(DF2, dir = "long", varying = TRUE, v.names = unique(names0))
```

**Note:**

```
Lines <- "      A      B      C      A      B      C 
1    a1     b1     c1     a5     b5     c5
2    a2     b2     c2     a6     b6     c6
3    a3     b3     c3     a7     b7     c7
4    a4     b4     c4     a8     b8     c8"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, as.is = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)

DF2 <- setNames(DF, c("A1", "B1", "C1", "A2", "B2", "C2")) # test input
```

**Upate:**  A number of simplifications. Also added `DF2` in Note at end and discuss in each alternative how to modify the code to deal with it.  (A general method might be just to reduce DF2 to DF as I discussed in the comments below.)

Comment: This is one of those occasions when `reshape` really shines. Although you don't need the `rep` when creating varying I don't think. `split(seq_len(nc), seq_len(k))`

Comment: Nice simplification.  Actually one could just split on `names(DF)` which is what I've done now.

Comment: I don't need to do the `setNames(DF, 1:nc)` part. It seems to work fine without it.

Comment: I thought that too originally but in fact if you examine the output then without that it is wrong.

Comment: Ah... I see. Admittedly, using the same column names is just asking for trouble.

Comment: If you go down that path, might as well take advantage of `reshape`'s name guessing `names(DF) <- paste0(names(DF), ave(names(DF), names(DF), FUN=seq_along)); reshape(DF, dir = "long", varying=TRUE, sep="")`

Comment: Thank you very much G. Grothendieck and all the others who answered. The code you provided seem to require the variable to repeat with exactly the same names in order to work. I edited my question to include a slightly different situation in which the names change, but I still want to do the same thing. Can you help also in such case?

Comment: The situation in the question's edit can be reduced to the situation given in the original question by first removing any trailing numbers from the names  using `names(DF) <- sub("\\d*$", "", names(DF))`.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

We can split column-wise then row bind ([using G. Grothendieck's example data, DF and DF2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46841373/680068)):

```
library(data.table) #rbindlist for binding columns with different names.

k <- 3
nr <- nrow(DF)
nc <- ncol(DF)

rbindlist(split.default(DF, rep(1:(nc/k), each = k)))
#     A  B  C
# 1: a1 b1 c1
# 2: a2 b2 c2
# 3: a3 b3 c3
# 4: a4 b4 c4
# 5: a5 b5 c5
# 6: a6 b6 c6
# 7: a7 b7 c7
# 8: a8 b8 c8

rbindlist(split.default(DF2, rep(1:(nc/k), each = k)), use.names = FALSE)
#    A1 B1 C1
# 1: a1 b1 c1
# 2: a2 b2 c2
# 3: a3 b3 c3
# 4: a4 b4 c4
# 5: a5 b5 c5
# 6: a6 b6 c6
# 7: a7 b7 c7
# 8: a8 b8 c8
```

Answer (score 1):

`stack` and `unstack`

```
NEWDF=stack(DF)
NEWDF$ind=as.character(NEWDF$ind)
NEWDF$ind=rep(NEWDF$ind[1:(dim(NEWDF)[1]/2)],2)
unstack(NEWDF)
   A  B  C
1 a1 b1 c1
2 a2 b2 c2
3 a3 b3 c3
4 a4 b4 c4
5 a5 b5 c5
6 a6 b6 c6
7 a7 b7 c7
8 a8 b8 c8
```

Answer (score 1):

We colud use `bind_rows` from `dplyr` package:

```
df1 <- df[,1:3]
df2 <- df[,4:6]
colnames(df2) <- colnames(df1) # for differing colnames
bind_rows(df1, df2)
```

Output:

```
  A     B     C    
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 a1    b1    c1   
2 a2    b2    c2   
3 a3    b3    c3   
4 a4    b4    c4   
5 a5    b5    c5   
6 a6    b6    c6   
7 a7    b7    c7   
8 a8    b8    c8
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the nth columns stacked into separated data.frames, stored in a list:

```
library(tidyr)
cols <- ncol(dat)
set_width <- 3
result <- dat %>%
  gather(key, value) %>%
  split(., rep(rep(1:set_width, each = nrow(dat)), ncol(dat)/set_width))
```

**Data:**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "      A      B      C      A      B      C 
1    a1     b1     c1     a5     b5     c5
                  2    a2     b2     c2     a6     b6     c6
                  3    a3     b3     c3     a7     b7     c7
                  4    a4     b4     c4     a8     b8     c8", check.names = TRUE)
```

(If your variable names are non-unique, i.e., they repeat exactly, insert `janitor::clean_names()` into the pipeline).

Answer (score 0):

To complete with a more recent `tidyverse` approach, using `pivot_longer`:

```r
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(dat, everything(),
             names_pattern = "([A-Z]+)\\d+", 
             names_to = ".value", cols_vary = "slowest")

#   A     B     C    
# 1 a1    b1    c1   
# 2 a2    b2    c2   
# 3 a3    b3    c3   
# 4 a4    b4    c4   
# 5 a5    b5    c5   
# 6 a6    b6    c6   
# 7 a7    b7    c7   
# 8 a8    b8    c8
```

Data:

```r
dat <- read.table(text = "      A1      B1      C1      A2      B2      C2 
1    a1     b1     c1     a5     b5     c5
                  2    a2     b2     c2     a6     b6     c6
                  3    a3     b3     c3     a7     b7     c7
                  4    a4     b4     c4     a8     b8     c8")
```