# Reshape a dataframe from 1 x 4 to 2 x 2?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working with the dplyr library and have created a dataframe in a pipe that looks something like this:

```
a <- c(1, 2, 2)
b <- c(3, 4, 4)
data <- data.frame(a, b)
data %>% summarize_all(c(min, max))
```

which gives me this dataframe:

```
a_fn1 b_fn1 a_fn2 b_fn2
    1     3     2     4
```

and I am trying to reshape this dataframe so that the output of the pipe stacks multiple columns on top of each other in several rows that look like this:

```
A  B
----
1  3
2  4
```

How would I go about this? I do not want to change how the functions are called because the summarize_all function helps me achieve the values I am looking for. I just want to know how to change this dataframe to the shape such that each value in each row is the value of the summarize function for the given column.

Comment: You should make a reproducible example, please read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/6574038

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully the edits I made made this a more reproducable example.

Comment: I'm sorry, it is still unclear to me what your goal is. However, for reshaping dataframes with tidyverse, check out `tidyr::pivot_longer` and `tidyr::pivot_wider`

Comment: Pivot longer does not do what I want it to do because it makes column names into a single row. I just want to stack the result of the summarize function to individual rows for each function instead of a single row including all of the outputs of the functions

Comment: Related post, there is a dplyr/tidy solution, try it out: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46841179/680068

Comment: before `summarize_all()` try doing a `group_by_all()` like so: `data %>% group_by_all() %>% summarize_all(c(min, max)) %>% ungroup()`

Comment: group_by_all() just returns the function called on single rows which is not what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: This doesn't exactly work because I need to feed parameters to the functions in the list.

Comment: Another related post, getting min max for each column: `apply(data, 2, range)` https://stackoverflow.com/q/26893178/680068

Comment: the min and max functions are just placeholders for the functions I am trying to run.

Comment: `data %>%  summarize_all(c(min, max)) %> pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = '.value', names_pattern = '([a-z]+)_.*')`

Answer (score 2):

First, naming your functions in `summarize_all()` will make them appear in the result for easier wrangling.

Then, you can use `pivot_longer()` with the special `.value` sentinel in `names_to` to achieve what you want:

```r
library(tidyverse)
a <- c(1, 2, 2)
b <- c(3, 4, 4)
data <- data.frame(a, b)
data %>% 
  summarize_all(c(min=min, max=max)) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to=c(".value", "variable"), names_pattern="(.)_(.+)")
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   variable     a     b
#>   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 min          1     3
#> 2 max          2     4
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Depending on what output you want, you can even switch the order to `c("variable", ".value")`.

Note that `summarize_all()` is deprecated and that you might want to use the new, more verbous syntax: `summarize(across(everything(), c(min=min, max=max)))`.

Comment: actually in my real example I use summarize_if as I require the predicate to run the functions I need.

Comment: @Anonymous you should check the help of `?across`, it can handle predicates as well.

Comment: Noted. However for now the result of my summarize is the correct output. This solution however breaks apart the names of my columns and does not give me a solution as it outputs multiple rows for each function.

Comment: @Anonymous this solution gives the expected output that you wrote in your question (with the extra "variable" column that you may remove). If this is not what you want you need to explain it better and give us another expected output. This might even belong in another question, I'm not sure.